# remapping <space> and <backspace> in Vimpulse to scroll more

Tags: emacs, viper-mode, viper, vimpulse

In [Some Thoughts on Emacs and Vim](https://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/some-thoughts-on-emacs-and-vim/), Shinobu recommendation to remap <space> and <backspace> doesn't work on Emacs 2.3.1 with Vimpulse 0.5.

What am I doing wrong?

```
;; from .emacs

; simulate vim's "nnoremap <space> 10<c-e>10j"
(vimpulse-map " " (lambda ()
                     (interactive)
                     (next-line 10)
                     (viper-scroll-up-one 10)
                     ))

; simulate vim's "nnoremap <backspace> 10<c-y>10k"
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map [backspace] (lambda ()
                     (interactive)
                     (previous-line 10)
                     (viper-scroll-down-one 10)
                     ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd help to know what isn't working.

The following works for me, as in <kbd>SPC</kbd> and <kbd>backspace</kbd> scroll by 10 when in command mode (Vi state):

```
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map [backspace]
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (previous-line 10)
    (viper-scroll-down-one 10)))

(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map (kbd "SPC")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (next-line 10)
    (viper-scroll-up-one 10)))
```

That's using [vimpulse.el version 0.5](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-es/vimpulse.el) and `viper-expert-level` 5.

Comment: That works. Should I ever use (vimpulse-map) in place of (define-key)?

Comment: @Natan I'm not a vimpulse expert, so I don't know when `vimpulse-map` is useful or not.

Comment: OK. Last question: How did you know to use `[backspace]` and not `<backspace>`? According to `C-h k` `<backspace>` is the correct binding, yet only `[backspace]` works.

Comment: Actually, what I'd prefer to use is a call to `kbd`, which is much easier to use.  You're almost there.  Once you've done the `C-h k`, you correctly saw that the key maps to `<backspace>`, now, to use that in the call to `define-key`, you just do `(kbd "<backspace>")` (basically cut/paste from the *Help* buffer into the string passed to kbd.  I wasn't 100% sure the key you were hitting was the same as that, but I'll update the answer appropriately.

Comment: Great. Thank you for helping me solve future questions on my own.